# Javascript, Vue JS displaying values

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Beginner here 
I am having some issues displaying data using Vue js.

I have 3 arrays.
 I would like to display, Array 1 value[0] and than Array 2 value[0] and than Array 3 value[0]

Arrays example:

```
tableDataSlackStart [ "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z", "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z", "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"]
tableDataCurrentTurning [ "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z", "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z", "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"]
tableDataSlackStop [ "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z", "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z", "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"]
```

Show date

```
<div class="stuff">
        <div class="start">{{tableDataSlackStart}}</div>
        <div class="turn">{{tableDataCurrentTurning}}</div>
        <div class="stop">{{tableDataSlackStop}}</div>
</div>
```

At the moment i get the complete array in each div.

I want the data to display something like this.

```
    <div class="stuff">
        <div class="start">{{tableDataSlackStart[0]}}</div>
        <div class="turn">{{tableDataCurrentTurning[0]}}</div>
        <div class="stop">{{tableDataSlackStop[0]}}</div>
</div>
<div class="stuff">
        <div class="start">{{tableDataSlackStart[1]}}</div>
        <div class="turn">{{tableDataCurrentTurning[1]}}</div>
        <div class="stop">{{tableDataSlackStop[1]}}</div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to achieve it, with out duplicating the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you using Vue?

Comment: share live demo  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I would format the data differently:

```
tableData: [{
        slackStart: '',
        currentTurning: '',
        slackStop: ''
    }, {
        slackStart: '',
        currentTurning: '',
        slackStop: ''
    }, {
        slackStart: '',
        currentTurning: '',
        slackStop: ''
    }]
```

to format the data, you could do something like this

```
tableData = tableDataSlackStart.map(function (value, key) {
    return {
        slackStart: value,
        currentTurning: tableDataCurrentTurning[key] || "no Data",
        slackStop: tableDataSlackStop[key] || "no Data"
    };
});
```

this will only work properly if the arrays are all the same length and the SlackStart has the most number of entries.

This would enable you to do something like so:

```
<div v-for="data in tableData">
    <div class="start">{{ data.slackStart }}</div>
    <div class="turn">{{ data.currentTurning }}</div>
    <div class="stop">{{ data.slackStop }}</div>
</div>
```

If you can provide more information about how you are using Vue, I can give more guidance.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how you added the arrays together in tableData. I had so much trouble with this before.

Comment: @charmGeld I added that seemingly before you made the comment! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

ff their lengths are as same, you can code like this:

```
<div v-for="(data, index) in tableDataSlackStart" :key="index">
<div class="stop">{{ data }}</div>
<div class="start">{{ tableDataCurrentTurning[index] }}</div>
<div class="turn">{{ tableDataSlackStop[index] }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by arranging your data like

```
var tableDataSlackStart = [ "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z", "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z", "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"] 

var tableDataCurrentTurning = [ "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z", "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z", "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"]

var tableDataSlackStop = [ "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z", "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z", "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"]

 var arr = [
        tableDataSlackStart,
        tableDataCurrentTurning,
        tableDataSlackStop
      ];

  arr.forEach(data => console.log(data[0]));
```